# Running JUnit tests together with Java project

Tags: java, junit

I'm writing code in Intellij and have a JUnit test class included in a project and i understand that running of JUnit should always be done at build time.

Is there a way to first run the JUnit and only if there were no test error run the project itself ? I want them to run together with 1 click (NOT run them seperately/manually).

Also, i would like the above to work even when the project is packed as a .jar file.

How can it be done ?

Thanks !

Comment: Go into "Edit run configurations" and add a task for "Before launch".

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij:

Run -> Edit Configurations

1. Create a JUnit configuration for your tests
2. Create a Run configuration for your project. 
   And on "Before Launch": Add -> Run Another Configuration and choose the one created at point 1. 
   It doesn't matter how your project is packed (jar, ...)

Normally this is done by using a build management tool like: maven, gradle, ant. In this way the build tool will run tests for you and stop if they fail.

With maven, it's just a command: `mvn clean package exec:java` which will compile code, build project, run tests and execute your code.

See example project: https://github.com/HaveACupOfJava/maven-jar-demo

Comment: Found it :) Thanks a lot. Is there a way to run the project itself ONLY if all test have passed successfully ? (After adding the extra configuration)

Or will it have to be an explicit exit() statement inside the code (for the fail case) of the test class ?

Comment: Consider using a build management tool. In this way the other developers from your team don't need to setup the same config in their IDE. See my edited answer.

Comment: Is there a way to tell mvn (using its commands) to run the project only if the Junit succeeded ? If not then how can it be configured  ? Thanks :)

Comment: Maven does that by default, stops execution if tests fail, no need for extra config.

Comment: And how will the above work when the project is packed as a jar file ?

Comment: See example project in updated response. Let me know if that works for you.